# Help promote music.SE through your already-existing activities

Tags: discussion, site-promotion

While I am working on ways to promote this great community to new people, there are a couple of things that you, the community, can do to help us spread the word...just through sites and activities you're already doing!

Some ways to help include, but are not limited to:

1. Put your Stack Exchange flair in your email signatures, on your blog, or anywhere else on the Internet you inhabit! (If you don't know how to do that: go to your profile page. On the second set of tabs - underneath all your profile info - select the "flair" tab. You can then copy the HTML code for either site-specific flair, or a combined piece of flare that shows up to 7 sites where you have 200+ reputation. Pretty neat, huh?)
2. Check out [StackTack](https://stackapps.com/questions/518/stacktack-a-javascript-widget-you-can-stick-anywhere) - "a Javascript app you can stick anywhere!" If you have a blog, consider using this widget to insert a particular question from Music.SE into a post or on the sidebar.
3. If you have a blog, consider throwing up a link to music.stackexchange.com (your profile or the general site) or writing a review of the site. If you write a review, feel free to write a genuine and honest review of the site. You know the site, its strengths and weaknesses; we don't mind you sharing both. Of course, it would be great if you could talk about what you use it for, how you've found it helpful, etc., and if you talk about areas that you think could use some improvement, let us know here in meta (certainly doesn't hurt to offer suggestions, too!).
4. If you see a great question or great answer (yours or someone else's), use those social buttons! Share them on Facebook and Twitter. (Did you know you can [earn](https://music.stackexchange.com/badges/59/announcer) [some](https://music.stackexchange.com/badges/61/publicist) cool [badges](https://music.stackexchange.com/badges/60/booster) by sharing links to this site through the "link" button on each question and answer?)
5. Next time you're shopping for music gear, tell your local music shop owner about us. If they have slow days at work and are on the computer anyway trying to pass the time, they might want to share their expertise online!
6. Mention music.stackexchange.com as a resource for any aspiring musician, music teacher, or any member of the general public you encounter who has a question that can be answered by this site.

What do you think of these ideas? Do you have any other suggestions for simple ways to get the word out about Stack Exchange as a resource for musicians?

Answer (score 1):

Great ideas! However, I think we need to go a little bit further as far as off-line promotion is concerned (namely, points 5 and 6). It's all too easy for people to forget about "the website that person told me about the other day", and many of us don't check information right away. This could be addressed by having templates available for "business" cards and small (but still noticeable) A4 posters that people could distribute or hang on the walls at their local music school.

Comment: The business cards idea starts to work well once the site graduates and has a recognisable brand - security.SE graduated not long ago, and the business cards have already been a useful talking point.

Comment: I agree that having real-world artifacts to leave in shops or hand to people would be great. I'll see if our designer has any time in the next few weeks to create some sort of flyer; if he does, either he or I will post it here so that any user can download and distribute them. By the same token, we also encourage our community's creativity: if anyone here wants to design flyers or business cards, they are more than welcome to. We just ask that if you make something great, you post it here on meta so others can use it, too! :)

Comment: P.S. Since this site is still in beta and doesn't have a custom theme, you can use the general Stack Exchange logo or icon and just add the word "Music" somewhere on the page (and in the URL, if you include it, which is probably a good idea). Those files are publicly available here: http://stackexchange.com/about/logos

Answer (score 1):

Have you thought about sponsoring one of the music festivals - I don't know enough about this, but there are certainly sponsorship opportunities to get your brand on posters, laminates, flyers, screen adverts etc.

I'm still up for music SE stickers for amps, flight cases etc once the site graduates - would have them on my kit and we play some decent venues, festivals etc and gig with some big names (biggest so far was KMFDM - who would have been up for the odd sticker added to the side of their flight cases I reckon :-) )